# Why can't I use forEach to traverse a tree?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I've written a function to check if my tree contains a value. Each tree/ subtrees have an array of children which my function traverses. Why can't I use forEach to traverse the children of the tree?

```js
function Tree (value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function (node) {
  this.children.push(node);
  return true;
};

Tree.prototype.contains = function (value) {
  if (this.value === value) return true;
  this.children.forEach(el => {
    return el.contains(value);
  });
  return false;
};

let myTree = new Tree(2);
let firstLevelChild = new Tree(7);
let secondLevelChild = new Tree(3);
myTree.addChild(firstLevelChild);
firstLevelChild.addChild(secondLevelChild);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myTree, null, 2));
console.log('2: ',myTree.contains(2))
console.log('7: ',myTree.contains(7))
console.log('3: ',myTree.contains(3))
```

Comment: please add `Tree` as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry but I don't understand :( You mean as a tag? --edit ok added...

Comment: @IsabellaChen: No, she means a minimal version of your `Tree` function and the `addChild` method, so the snippet actually runs and demonstrates the problem. There's no point to a snippet that isn't a [mcve], it may as well just be a code block.

Comment: i mean, where do you define `Tree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `forEach` doesn't care what the return value of its callback is. It keeps looping, no matter what, and doesn't itself have a (meaningful) return value.

You wanted [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and to *return* its result:

```
Tree.prototype.contains = function (value) {
  if (this.value === value) return true;
  return this.children.some(el => {
    return el.contains(value);
  });
};
```

or even more compact (if that's a goal):

```
Tree.prototype.contains = function (value) {
  return this.value === value || this.children.some(el => el.contains(value));
};
```

Live Example:

```js
function Tree (value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.children = [];
}

Tree.prototype.addChild = function (node) {
  this.children.push(node);
  return true;
};

Tree.prototype.contains = function (value) {
  return this.value === value || this.children.some(el => {
    return el.contains(value);
  });
};

let myTree = new Tree(2);
let firstLevelChild = new Tree(7);
let secondLevelChild = new Tree(3);
myTree.addChild(firstLevelChild);
firstLevelChild.addChild(secondLevelChild);
console.log('2: ',myTree.contains(2));
console.log('7: ',myTree.contains(7));
console.log('3: ',myTree.contains(3));
```

`some` calls its callback until the callback returns a truthy value, and then stops. If the callback ever returns a truthy value, `some` returns `true`; if not, `some` returns `false`.